# matplotlib install failing, can't find the right numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've installed numpy 1.6.1, and now I'm attempting to install matplotlib on OSX 10.6.
I make the following call to install matplotlib:

```
    make -f make.osx PREFIX=/../deps fetch deps mpl_install_std
```

And it fails with the error

```
* numpy 1.4 or later is required; you have 1.2.1
```

I checked my numpy version and it returns 1.6.1

What gives?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: This has been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566111/installing-python-modules-on-osx-using-easy-install-or-setup-py-install) before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's picking up another version of python than you get from the command line. Try something like

```
make -f make.osx PREFIX=... PYTHON=`which python` ...
```

to ensure it uses the same python.