# Issues installing numpy on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, numpy, python-2.6

I am having trouble installing numpy with `easy_install` (or any other means). I get errors relating to missing executables but I don't know what to do with that information. This is the output I get when I run `sudo easy_install numpy`:

```
$ sudo easy_install numpy
Password:
Searching for numpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Reading http://numpy.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1369&package_id=175103
Reading http://numeric.scipy.org
Best match: numpy 1.6.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-    1.6.1.zip#md5=462c22b8eb221c78ddd51de98fbb5979
Processing numpy-1.6.1.zip
Running numpy-1.6.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-    1.6.1/egg-dist-tmp-2IwG3W
Running from numpy source directory.non-existing path in '/private/tmp/easy_install-    pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
Could not locate executable g77
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py:126:     UserWarning: Env. variable MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set to 10.3
  warnings.warn(s)
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler (    /usr/bin/../libexec/as/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/as/ppc/as) for     architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/i386/as for architecture i386
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/arm/as for architecture arm
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccu9Tt6I.out (No such file or directory)
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler (    /usr/bin/../libexec/as/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/as/ppc/as) for     architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/i386/as for architecture i386
/usr/bin/../libexec/as/arm/as for architecture arm
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccu9Tt6I.out (No such file or directory)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/easy_install", line     9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.24', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1883, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1864, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1887, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/co    re.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 349, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 589, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 619, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1086, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1075, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 30, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 72, in run
    return func()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 196, in <module>

  File "setup.py", line 189, in setup_package

  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in     setup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/co    re.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cm    d.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py",     line 8, in run
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cm    d.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/di    st.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",     line 152, in run
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",     line 163, in build_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",     line 298, in build_library_sources
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",     line 385, in generate_sources
  File "/private/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/core/setup.py", line     696, in get_mathlib_info

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252:     RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute     import
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/atexit.py",     line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line     252, in clean_up_temporary_directory
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/atexit.py",     line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-pTnrFa/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line     252, in clean_up_temporary_directory
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
```

The questions I have seen relating to this don't seem to have the same issues I am having. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Is that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256397/python-easy-install-fails-with-assembler-for-architecture-ppc-not-installed-on helping you ? Ie: env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install ... ?

Comment: Better, look the second answer, you can get ride of theses error.

Comment: Nope – tried both already, it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using OS X, you need to have MacPorts installed.
http://www.macports.org/install.php

MacPorts in turn requires XCode with command line tools. For those using snow-leopard, XCode 4 as available through iTunes won't work. How to get version 3.2 is explained here:
[Can I get Xcode for Leopard still?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596164/can-i-get-xcode-for-leopard-still)

Here are some other hints:
[Installing Python modules on OSX using easy_install or setup.py install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566111/installing-python-modules-on-osx-using-easy-install-or-setup-py-install)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to get specific header files installed (a static library and development tools) for building Python modules. For **linux** it's **python-dev** package, what provides it, as for **OS X,** I'm not sure, but I believe **xcode** dependencies would include the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development tools (xcode).